# Rotation of a dipole in different situations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, torque

I know that a dipole performs only rotational motion when placed in a uniform field, while it performs both rotational and translational when placed in a non-uniform electric field.
**However, under what circumstances will it perform pure translational motion?**

Comment: When it is aligned with a non-uniform electric field

Answer (score 1):

The dipole translates if there is a difference in field strength (in magnitude or direction) over the length of the dipole, and it rotates if it is not aligned with the electric field.

It follows that the dipole will purely rotate about its centre in a uniform field if it is not aligned with the field vector, and it will purely translate in a non-uniform field if it is aligned with the field vector.